# is this code vulnerable to SQL Injections?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, security, code-injection

page loads you have to fill some text boxes and then click add:

```
tbSpyReports spyReport = new tbSpyReports();
spyReport.sgCityLevel = Convert.ToInt32(tbCityLevel.Text);
spyReport.sgCityName = tbCityName_insert.Text; 
....
spyReport.insert();
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);


SqlConnection con = ikaConn.getConn();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO spyReports(cityName, playerName, cityId,      islandId, cordX, cordY, " + "cityLevel, cityWall, cityWarehouse, Wood, Wine, Marble, Crystal, Sulfur, hasArmies) VALUES(" + "@cityName, @playerName, @cityId, @islandId, @cordX, @cordY, " + "@cityLevel, @cityWall, @cityWarehouse, @Wood, @Wine, @Marble, @Crystal, @Sulfur, @hasArmies)", con);
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("cityName", this.cityName));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("playerName", this.playerName));
....
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.Dispose();
```

Comment: You're using a parameterized query so you are fine.

Comment: You should spend 5 minutes reading about what Sql Injections is. You will quickly realise your code is not.

Comment: @CraigW. ,Valamas , so even if i split the query to multiply lines using + +  and then using parameters im fine? also what exactly happens in there that is making it"safe"

Comment: You are not taking unsanitized user-provided values and making them part of your query. That is why your code is safe.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be vulnerable to traditional SQL injection of this form:

```
statement = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name ='" + userName + "';"
```

as you're using parameterized queries.

Comment: Mind explaining multiple downvotes?  I believe I answered the question correctly.  Is it the slightly tangential memory injection attack reference?

Comment: No user input is involved in the string concatenations so mind explaining how that can possibly be an attack vector?

Comment: @MartinSmith a reflective memory attack takes a memory space and replaces it with another.  Any and all string literals are vulnerable to this, and it's very difficult to do, and to protect from.  I'm not suggesting user input has anything to do with this.  [Take a read](http://www.softbox.co.uk/pub/lumension_reflective-memory-injection.pdf)

Comment: Where should I be looking to see anything at all about string concatenation in that doc?

Comment: from the article: "Before an attacker can use RMI, the attacker must
be able to run a small amount of executable code
and must have downloaded or otherwise copied
the bytes of malicious DLL into memory." and doing multiple string concatenations allows an attacker to do this?

Comment: @MartinSmith the point is that any code that uses string literals for SQL code is vulnerable, as they're stored in human-readable memory locations.  But whatever, I'll just take the downvotes if you think it's irrelevant - I think it's an important consideration

Comment: @guest this is done via a malformed response and a buffer overflow.  Do you want me to just remove that part or something?  I've yet to see anyone tell me the answer itself is incorrect

Comment: There.  Removed the (useful) part so that it's simpler.  Now is there a problem with this answer?

Comment: Thanks, that part seemed too much of a stretch. It's like saying that the code is vulnerable because it runs on a server, and an attacker can put a virus on the server to execute an arbitrary query.

Comment: Sure.  I thought it was relevant as it was tagged code-injection, but I guess not.